# Concentration of $\ell_2$ norm of a vector sampled from a distribution

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions, measure-concentration, gaussian, expectation

Let $X=(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$, where $X_i \sim P_{p_i}(0,\frac{1}{\lambda})$ are iid, $P_{p_i}$ is sub gaussian distribution for $i^\text{th}$ element, and 0 and $1/\lambda$ are mean and variance.

I'm looking for a result on the concentration of $\|X\|_2^2$ something of the form  $E \|X\|_2^2 \leq c$ with $P(\|X\|_2^2 \geq c+\epsilon)\leq f(\epsilon)$. What happens when all the distribution are normals?

I have asked a similar question on https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3798100/concentration-of-l2-norm-of-a-vector-sampled-from-a-distribution

Comment: I think the first sentence should read “where the $X_i$ are iid subgaussian variables with mean 0 and finite variance.” If they are all iid, then the notation $P_{p_i}$ is needlessly complicated, and in any case the use of $1/\lambda$ seems needlessly complicated too.

Comment: I agree with Matt F. that your notation is unnecessarily clumsy. In any case, are you aware that $\|X\|^2$ concentrates around $n\mbox{var}(X_1)$ ?

Comment: @MattF. Thank you for your suggestions, I will change it.

Comment: @dohmatob I don't know about that concentration.

Comment: Isn't this **exactly the same** question your asked here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3798100/concentration-of-l2-norm-of-a-vector-sampled-from-a-distribution ?

Comment: @dohmatob It is the same question, that is why I have linked. I have not received a response there so I posted here.

Comment: I think it's agains the policy of either of the sites to re-post duplicates (which kinda makes sense...).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WLOG, let $\lambda = 1$ (rescale your problem appropriately, if necessary). Then, it is well-known consequence of [Bernstein's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernstein_inequalities_(probability_theory)) (e.g see theorem 3.1.1 of "High-dimensional Probability" book by R. Vershynin) that

$$
\mathbb P\left(\left|\frac{\|X\|^2}{n}-1\right| \le \epsilon\right) \ge 1 - 2e^{-Cn\min(\epsilon,\epsilon^2)},\;\forall \epsilon \ge 0.
$$

Here, $C$ is a constant which is independent of $n$. In other words, $\|X\|^2$ has good (exponential / Gaussian) concentration around the value $n$.